# Divide 3D space into smaller cubes

Tags: r, 3d

I have a set of points in 3D. I want to divide the entire volume occupied by the points into 128X128X128 number of cubes. And I want to count the number of points in each cube. Can you suggest how to do this in R?

I have tried rgb and scatterplot3d packages but did not find the solution there. Also, I need to color these cubes in accordance with their numbers. Please suggest how to go about it.

Although it will not influence the solution, but my data is not symmetrically spread in all directions. So  will divide this quantity: max(x,y,z) by 128 to get the edge length of each cube.

Thank you.

Comment: a reproducible example would be nice.  The result will be a vector of length 128^3=2097152, so it may require some computational care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that what you want to do, then here's an attempt.

```
dat <- as.data.frame(replicate(3, runif(10000))) # Toy data

n <- 3 # set to 128, the number of cubes in each direction
cut_dat <- lapply(dat, cut, breaks = seq(0, 1, l = n + 1)) # Break into cubes
do.call(table, cut_dat)  # Cross tabulate to count
#, , V3 = (0,0.333]
#
#               V2
#V1              (0,0.333] (0.333,0.667] (0.667,1]
#  (0,0.333]           383           361       379
#  (0.333,0.667]       362           382       371
#  (0.667,1]           389           358       370
#
#, , V3 = (0.333,0.667]
#
#               V2
#V1              (0,0.333] (0.333,0.667] (0.667,1]
#  (0,0.333]           345           383       372
#  (0.333,0.667]       374           388       381
#  (0.667,1]           383           368       373
#
#, , V3 = (0.667,1]
#
#               V2
#V1              (0,0.333] (0.333,0.667] (0.667,1]
#  (0,0.333]           342           355       360
#  (0.333,0.667]       386           386       374
#  (0.667,1]           346           372       357
```

So you get a 3d array with the counts. I have reduced the number of cubes to 3 in each direction to display the concept.

**Edit**: Gavin Kelly's suggestion can also be done here

```
table(cut_dat[[1]]:cut_dat[[2]]:cut_dat[[3]])
```

to get another data representation.

Or even more human readable:

```
tab2 <- expand.grid(lapply(cut_dat, levels))
tab2$freq <- table(cut_dat[[1]]:cut_dat[[2]]:cut_dat[[3]])
head(tab, n = 4)
#             V1            V2        V3 freq
#1     (0,0.333]     (0,0.333] (0,0.333]  374
#2 (0.333,0.667]     (0,0.333] (0,0.333]  379
#3     (0.667,1]     (0,0.333] (0,0.333]  384
#4     (0,0.333] (0.333,0.667] (0,0.333]  377
```

Comment: It is working perfectly fine! Thanks @AEBilgrau. Could you also tell me how to plot these points so that each cube is colored according to it`s frequency?

Answer (score 4):

If variables x, y and z are vectors of coordinates, then you can get the box-number of each coordinate by

```
xbox <- as.integer(cut(x, breaks=128))
ybox <- as.integer(cut(y, breaks=128))
zbox <- as.integer(cut(z, breaks=128))
```

Hopefully, most boxes will be empty, and you can do something along the lines of

```
xyzbox <- paste(xbox, ybox, zbox, sep=":")
table(xyzbox)
```

to give you a list of occupied boxes, and their count of points